# Is there any way the restful URL not to be displayed in the URL box in browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assume that there are Post and Comment models.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In config/routes.rb

```
resources posts do
  resources comments
end
```

In this situation, if we retrieve the comment id 12 of the post id 1, the proper restful routing path will be as follows:

```
post_comments_path(@comment.post, @comment)
```

and this will be displayed in the URL box of the client's browser as follows:

```
post/1/comments/12
```

What I am concerning in this context is whether there are ways to hide the above url string including ids and replace others expression excluding id data, for exmaple, "post/comments", or not.

If this questions is not significant, although id data are exposed in the query string, I am curious about whether there is any security problem or not.

Comment: No. Why on earth would you want to do this? If a user is making a request, the URL will *always* be visible. Why would you hide it? What purpose would that serve?

Comment: In fact, I totally agree with you. Somebody asked me about this. He insisted on that, if ids were exposed in URL box, hacking could be possible. Is it really possible?

Comment: If someone enters the id of a post that they *shouldn't* have access to, that is the responsibility of the controller/endpoint that is serving the request to block that person from accessing that resource. Obfuscating the URLs is a pathetic solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. I appreciate your kind comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to checkout a Railscast on displaying model attributes in the url. However, its much more easy to manage your resources keeping the `id` in the url.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

Even on the Railscast, you'll find Ryan Bates talking of tricky issues if you do not have the `id` in the url and simply have, say, name as `posts/name-of-post` instead of `posts/1`.

To change the url, all you need to do is override the `to_param` method that Rails uses to convert the model to a url. However, without passing the `id`, you'll need to modify your code in other places too.